# How to handle error of File Upload in NodeJS , when no file is uploaded

Tags: html, node.js, forms, file-upload

This is my code. I want to handle error, and also show a res.send message saying that no file is uploaded. how to do?

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {

   console.log(req.body);
console.log(req.files.formfile);
    let student = new studentRec(req.body);
    student.save();

    let image=req.files.formfile;

    image.mv('./static/images/'+image.name,(err,done)=>{
      if(!err){
          res.send('file uploaded');
      }
      else{
        res.send('cant save this file');
      }
    })
```

Comment: Why not using standard nodejs file uploader package such as multer?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the size of the uploaded file — if it's 0, there's no file uploaded. See the example:

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  console.log(req.files.formfile);
  let student = new studentRec(req.body);
  student.save();

  let image=req.files.formfile;

  if (image.size) === 0 {
    res.send('no file is uploaded');
  }

  image.mv('./static/images/'+image.name, (err,done)=>{
    if(!err){
        res.send('file uploaded');
    }
    else{
      res.send('cant save this file');
    }
  });
}
```